# CodeIgniter cron job Every minute(*****) not working in cloudways

Tags: cron, cloudways

I configured the cron job in Cloudways by choosing Every minute(*****) in basic tab. And it shows like this

```
*  *  *  *  *       wget http://example.com/cron/index
```

It runs only every 5 minutes. But I need to run this by every minute. I also tried this way too

```
*/1  *  *  *  *      wget http://example.com/cron/index
```

but it also run every 5 minutes.

Comment: Are you sure that Cloudways allow to run a task every minute? Is it included in your subscription? It may be a limit from the service itself.

Comment: Since UI suggests to choose "Every minute..." and then you can confirm (and that's some limitation at "example.com" side, f.i.) it runs only every 5 minutes, contacting Cloudways support with the supposed issue on their side sounds reasonable. Or try setting the cronjob directly [on the server](https://support.cloudways.com/en/articles/5124734-how-to-add-a-cron-job-via-ssh).